# how to set zeppelin note permission access control

Tags: shiro, apache-zeppelin

I was trying to use LDAP authorization manner to login and looks like the Reader could edit the entire Note Permission which supposed to be read only.

For example I am UserA, I am the owner and writer of the Notebook, and set UserB as the reader. However, once UserB logged in, s/he could remove the owner (UserA) and becomes as the Owner of the Notebook.

Would you please help resolve?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an known issue (in meantime). Looks like this is planned to be solved with version 0.9 (see comment in ZEPPELIN-3096).

Related Jira tasks in Zeppelin project:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3096
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3396

Until then the only known "workaround" might be to only set trustful persons as readers (not a really good option...).